# Function being identically zero in a region and disc around

Tags: complex-analysis

Sorry for my choice of title, I was not sure how to put.
At one part of the book below, the authors go like

### Theorem

[image]

And they applied this theorem in a proof of another result to define the following;
[image]
** Note that $f(z_0) = w_0$ and $R \subseteq \mathbb{C}$

### My question

How Theorem A.8 implies such disc defined above in the second image?

### Reference

Jones, Gareth A., and David Singerman. Complex functions: an algebraic and geometric viewpoint. Cambridge university press, 1987.

Comment: If there is no such disk, then there is a sequence $z_n \to z_0$ ($z_n\neq z_0$) for all $n$ such that $f(z_n)-w=0$ for all $n$. And $f(z)-w$ is analytic.

Comment: hmm, but $0$ (i.e., a constant function) being analytic isn't the issue, right?

Comment: In the proof it is assumed that $f$ is not identically $w_0$.

Comment: yeah. sorry, i should've worded differently like my question was how Thorem a.8 applies to get that assumption, could you tell me about this?

Comment: Okay, I think I got it, like in A.8, we assume that the sequence of points $z_i$ are associated evaluted to $0$ by $f$ but, you suggested that we can change it to $w_0$, right?

Comment: Theorem A.8 is applied to the new analytic function $g(z)=f(z)-w_0$, not to $f$ itself.

Comment: @geetha290krm Got it! it makes sense! Thank you for your series of answers!